# Hole-in-One. Small extension and socket fall into valve

Tags: engine, valve

I am very poor so I work on my house/SUV (2002 Ford Expedition) myself. Recent misfires had me changing coils and spark plugs. Well, everything is going fine until my extension comes off my socket wrench and falls into the spark plug hole. I was heart attack emotional. What are the chances of an extension and 8mm socket falling through the spark plug hole. I can not afford anything. Looking on line and watching videos, I decided to attempt to take the head gasket or whatever it's called to retrieve the socket. Not to mention that I really want some laughs when I tell you I turned the engine for like 10secs to see if it spit the extension out. I'm now stuck at the real big bolt that I have no wrench for. I was going to by-pass taking off the alternator but right now I'm just trying desperately to do something to make progress or admit defeat. Please tell me something I can do to get this extension with 8mm socket attached out of my cylinder.

Comment: Have you tried a flexible magnet through the plug hole- you may be lucky... Search on this site for 10mm socket - same problem different lication but answer has a picture of the tool.

Comment: So do you really think that the magnetic tool will have enough magnetic power to pull an small extension with 8mm socket ;up and out of the spark plug hole. I didn't wanted to waste the money and time on it. I will try to rent one tomorrow. Thanks, it's worth an try.

Comment: The Snap-On one I have has a small, but very strong magnet : picked up a 9/16 spanner in the past ...

Comment: Sounds great and I'm ecstatic about becoming a junior mechanic. Thanks.The snap on one is going to get a shoot at being my keep in glove box tool. I'll know tomorrow. My stress level has reached it's limit for today.

Comment: +1 just for the amount of pain I know you're going through. It's a tough mess, but can be dealt with.

Comment: Are you really sure its in there? I'd expect your attempt to crank to result in the motor locking up in a very nasty way. How long is the extension?  Whatever you think is the "head gasket" is not by the way.  If you had the head off you could put your hand in there and pull it out.

Comment: Very short extension about 3 1/2 inches I guess. I'm at point now where I have the tire off and eye balling the lower bolts on the valve cover. I stop because I really don't know what I'm doing. Can I retrieve the tool by removing the valve cover? If so, how? I have an2002 Ford Expedition and I'm working on the passenger side. How many bolts need to be removed? What tools do I need? Is a ratchet set enough? I read I need more hands but I'm a loner and have only two. What can I do to get this tool out of my engine?

Comment: Removing the valve cover won't do anything. There are tubes your spark plugs sit in that go straight through the valve cover. If you want to get to the cilinders, you'll need to remove the head. A ratchet set will not suffice, certainly not if you also want to reassemble the engine.

Comment: Also, if there really is a 3.5 inch steel extension inside one of the chambers, you should have definitely heard something really really bad when you turned over the engine for 10 seconds. Bad as in BANG TAK TAK TAK TAK or maybe just silence as it wouldn't be able to turn over.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately as you say you have turned the engine over for 10 seconds you may have seriously damaged both the piston and cylinder head etc. Not to mention the bar with 8mm socket attached, which could be very bent and trapped now. This is unless you are really lucky and the socket bar are just lying sideways on top of the piston, and not been compressed at all.

If the socket and bar sound like they are still loose in the cylinder then you can try a magnet to remove them, but following that even if you are successful in removing them you will certainly then need to do some investigation as to whether the piston/cylinder/head/valves are damaged from having the bar and socket trapped in there following the 10 sec rotation.

Comment: Well I don't hear anything as I poke a coat hanger down the spark plug hole.I took off the middle portion of the engine only to find out that I am still far from retrieving the extension and 8mm socket.purchased a magnetic pick up tool.hoping for the best. Well, when I got back to my dismantled 2002 ford expedition. I was disappointed again when serval attempts seem to fail as the magnetic tool was to large for the hole. Now I have been looking at hours of video on how to remove the cylinder head. Don't have the tools. Tell me, how long can I drive with an extension and 8mm socket in my engine

Comment: @DanielThompson Not at all.  You run a very high risk of ruining the engine if you even turn it over with that socket down there.