# I made a Hole-in-One. I dropped a Small extension and socket fall into valve.there's not in there

Tags: engine, cylinder-head

Two mechanics fell around in the spark plug hole and claim they didn't see anything or feel anything. That it probably popped out when I started the engine. What are the chances they are right? I'm still new to this and in spite of the expert advice Im still trying to take off the head to make sure. What do you think? Is it possible that it popped out when I started the engine to see if I could make it pop out. I really don't know what to do. I really don't know how to take off the head but I'm trying. Tell me what should I do?

Comment: if you tried to start the engine with a tool in the cylinder you would immediately do very serious damage.  Did it run for you? Id expect it to bind up and not even crank over.

Comment: What's going on here?  Why ask the same question two months apart with a new user account?  Did you loose track of the last account?  [Other question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/46847/12030)...

Comment: Yes, please use the process [detailed here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop something into the cylinder, the chances of it 'popping out' when you start the engine are so slight as to be ridiculous. Did either of the mechanics put a bore scope into the cylinder to see conclusively if there is anything in there?

If they didn't do that, do it yourself; Harbor Freight sells a cheapish camera that will fit through the spark plug hole. Taking the head off - unless you're doing other work that needs them off anyway - is a pretty extreme way of solving the problem, and may cause other more serious issues relating to the valves, gaskets and timing belt.

Comment: I have already took the passenger side valve cover off and unscrewed most of the bolts on the front cover. So you think it won't turn over if I reassemble it? I'm convince that if I can get the head off I could retrieve the tool no problem. I been watching videos on how to replace a timing chain step by step and that's how I achieve to get as far as I have. I only turn the engine for five seconds. I didn't even try to make it crank up I just turned the key and turned it back to the off position. I'm hoping for a miracle. 2002 ford expeditiontion 5.4 triton motor. Any step by step instructions.